# Jeder vs Jedermann

Tags: grammar, pronoun

> Ich bin Jedermanns Freund.
>
> Jeder spricht Deutsch in dieser Stadt.

Ist `Jedermann` altmodisch? Wenn ja, in welchem Jahr ist es altmodisch geworden?

Comment: Archaismen entstehen in den seltensten Fällen innerhalb eines bestimmten Jahres, die Häufigkeit des jeweiligen Gebrauchs nimmt vielmehr über einen längeren Zeitraum ab.

Comment: In welchem Jahr ist "thou" altmodisch geworden ;)

Comment: Vielleicht fragst du besser "wann ungefähr ist es altmodisch geworden", dann kann man ngram heranziehen oder gucken, ab wann Duden es mit "altmodisch" listet, falls das überhaupt der Fall ist, und eine Schätzung abgeben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Jedermann* ist ein fester Begriff, in dessen Konnotationen auch das Gleichsein aller Personen mitschwingt.  Er bezieht sich ausschließlich auf Individuen, unter bewusster Außerachtlassung ihrer Individualität.  Auch als Personifizierung des Gleichseins und implizit Unelitären kommt der Begriff vor: „Der Jedermann auf der Straße versteht die Wirtschaftspolitik ohnehin nicht.“

Es ist daher auch ein urdemokratischer Begriff und entsprechend nur in bestimmten Kontexten anwendbar bzw. kann er durch seine Anwendung einem Kontext eine dementsprechende starke Note verleihen.

So wäre z. B. die Aussage „Jedermann muss die Rutsche im Spaßbad im Sitzen oder Liegen benutzen“ ein Stilbruch, da eine soziopolitische Konnotation mit der Benutzung einer Rutsche schlecht einhergeht.  Die Aussage „Jedermann ist zur Wahl aufgerufen“ ist hingegen stilistisch stimmig.

*Jedermann* ist entsprechend auch Teil der gehobeneren Sprache und kann mit passenden Phrasen kombiniert werden, z. B. in „Jedermann möge sich diesem Gesetze unterwerfen“.

*Jeder* hingegen ist ein Alltagsbegriff, der nicht nur auf Personen eingeschränkt ist.  Als maskulines Pronomen kann es auch anderen Dingen vorangestellt sein („Jeder Schuss ein Treffer“, mit Dank an @user2024923 für das schöne Beispiel), und bei entsprechender Ellipsierung bleibt dieser Kontext erhalten: „Bäume wachsen ihr Leben lang, und jeder muss irgendwann gefällt werden.“

Answer (score 2):

Der Bezug ist ein anderer. Während "jeder" einfach alle Dinge einer Gruppe bezeichnet ("jeder Schuss ein Treffer", "jeder Hund kann bellen"), bezieht sich "jedermann" nur auf Menschen.

Comment: Das passt nicht ganz zur Frage, denn die Frage war "jeder" vs. "Jedermann" und nicht "jeder X" vs. "Jedermann". "Jeder" ohne was dazu bezieht sich auch nur auf Menschen.

Comment: @OregonGhost: stimmt, allerdings ist das "ohne was dazu" nicht immer klar erkennbar.  Im entsprechenden Kontext kann es sogar mehrdeutig sein.  "Schüler lernen das Einmaleins.  Jeder kann es, zumindest am Ende der dritten Klasse."

Answer (score 2):

"Jedermann" can only be used to refer to persons. It is also of a higher register and usually only used when a broad, all-encompassing term is needed; a law might state "Jedermann ist verpflichtet" = "Everybody must", e.g. But even then "jeder" could be used. Feminists will tell you that jeder_mann_ excludes women and should be avoided for that reason alone.

I can't think of a situation where you  mightn't be able to use "jede(r)" instead of "jedermann" (except whent alking about [the play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedermann), of course.)

Answer (score 2):

On important aspect that still seems to be missing from the answers is that you can't really form a **genitive** from the **pronoun** "jeder".

> *Ich bin jeders Freund.

This doesn't work, and what you usually do here is use "jedermann" instead, exactly as in your example:

> Ich bin jedermanns Freund.

Since "jedermann" does indeed sound a bit old-fashioned but is very useful for the case explained above, it is comparatively common in its genitive form "jedermanns".